# Access Violation in query in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a query say `qryDoABC` in function `DoABC`. When I call this function first time, all works fine but 2nd time when I call it, at line with qryDoABC do, it throws access violation exception.

```
procedure TMyForm.DoABC;
begin
  with qryDoABC do
  --
  -- 
end;
```

I googled and found out that I should check whether query is assigned or not. So now I am also checking whether query is assigned or not like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.DoABC;
begin
  if assigned qryDoABC then
  with qryDoABC do
  --
  -- 
end;
```

Now no exception is there because 2nd time query is not assigned. But I have to fire this qry 2nd time also. How should I assign this query 2nd time.

Full Code:

```
function TMyForm.DoABC:boolean;
begin
  try
    if assigned(qryDoABC)then 
    with qryDoABCdo
    begin
      Close  ;
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Text :=
        'Some query';

      Parameters.ParamByName('ABC').Value := ABC;
      Parameters.ParamByName('XYZ').Value := XYZ;
      Open;
      if (Recordcount = 0) then
        result := false
      else
      begin
        result := true;
      end;
      Close;
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      result := false;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Show the full code of your method. In the meantime, check if you don't `Free` that query object inside of it.

Comment: @TLama - I have added full code

Comment: The important part is missing here, since if you say that second time the query object is not assigned, then you must `Free` and/or `nil` it somewhere in your code.

Comment: @TLama - I have a Form1 and Form2. When I click on OK button of Form1, this query fires and if everything is fine I jump to Form2. Now if I press ESC there, I again come to Form1. Now if I press the button there I am getting the error. I am not using Free or Nil keyword anywhere

Comment: Note: There is no need to call clear if you are setting SQL.Text rather than using SQL.Add. I assume 'Some query' contains correctly named parameters. Also the `if RecordCount..` code code be more concisely be written `Result := RecordCount <> 0;`

Comment: There is no mention about more than one form nor about what you're doing with that object in your question at this time. That object is just released or its reference is pointed to `nil`, if you say it's not assigned second time you run your method. How, that's upon you to find. You have a debugger and the full, real code which tells you this. It saves you the time before we get all necessary information needed to answer this question. Now we can only guess. @Gerry, yes, those parameter lines are suspective unless there won't be database exception telling the parameter is not found.

Comment: @Gerry, ...and unless some exception would lead to losing reference to an existing object. This is impossible to answer at this time...

Comment: Show the code for the OnClick OK button on Form1.  Are you showing Form2 in Modal mode?  ie Form2.ShowModal?  Also, remove the with statement - if nothing else it will help reduce potential issues within the DoABC.  Is TMyForm actually Form1? My guess is that whatever instance of the form qryDoAB is residing on has been freed, whether directly by you or not.  If Assigned(qryDoABC) will still "pass" (return True) if qryDoABC.Free has been called.

Comment: @Jason - Hey Jason, removing "with" from query and writing the query in simple manner worked. Thanks. But whats the exact reason?

Comment: @NareshKumar Sorry.  Couldn't say for sure without seeing the full code - including the OnClick event.  Guess there's a classic reason why you shouldn't use a "with" statement :). Maybe the component doesn't have a close method in which case you were "closing" the Form and not the query.  But that's only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use Query Variable as a Local. Declare it in your function. And use 'TRY...FINALLY' to FREE query.

```
function TMyForm.DoABC:boolean;
var
  qryDoABC: TADOQuery;
begin
  try
    qryDoABC := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
    //Set Appropriate Connection String (below for MS-Access)
    qryDoABC.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=MDB_file';
    try
      with qryDoABC do
      begin
        SQL.Clear;
        SQL.Text := 'Some query';
        Parameters.ParamByName('ABC').Value := 'ABC';
        Parameters.ParamByName('XYZ').Value := 'XYZ';
        Open;
        if (Recordcount = 0) then
          result := false
        else
        begin
          result := true;
        end;
        Close;
      end;
    except
      on E : Exception do
      begin
        result := false;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(qryDoABC);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: By using this, I am not able to fire the query even the first time. I am getting access violation at first time now

Comment: @NareshKumar, sorry I forgot to add ConnectionString for Query, now check the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is qryDoABC a component on a form? If so, it is probably called the second time, if the form is removed. In that case, the form is either released too early or the query is called to late.

If you free the form manually, and the second query call is the result of an event handler, you can free the form using Release, this frees the form only when the message queue is handled so there are no pending messages for the form left.

Answer (score -1):

I was using TADOQuery Syntax like this

```
      with qryDoABC do
      begin
        SQL.Clear;
        SQL.Text := 'Some query';
        Parameters.ParamByName('ABC').Value := 'ABC';
        Parameters.ParamByName('XYZ').Value := 'XYZ';
        Open;
        if (Recordcount = 0) then
          result := false
        else
        begin
          result := true;
        end;
        Close;
      end;
```

But I discarded using `With` statement and wrote my code like this

```
qryDoABC.SQL.Clear;
    qryDoABC.SQL.Text := 'Some query';
    qryDoABC.Parameters.ParamByName('ABC').Value := 'ABC';
    qryDoABC.Parameters.ParamByName('XYZ').Value := 'XYZ';
    qryDoABC.Open;
    if (qryDoABC.Recordcount = 0) then
      result := false
    else
    begin
      result := true;
    end;
qryDoABC.Close;
```