# FireDac FDQuery Access Violation when called multiple times

Tags: delphi, memory-management, pascal, firedac

I have a strange error whereby FDQuery throws access violations when called multiple times in my function. Basically, I have a function which loops through a date range to produce a 2d array of data pulled from an SQL Table.

This function calls another one, who's job is to produce an array for one day. The function is being called this way :

```
while (date <= endDate) do
  begin
    try
        try
          FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
          FDQuery.Connection := FDConnection;

          ConvertData(date, DataTableName, iMaxVarIndex, iSiteID, FDQuery, DataArray,
            sCommentsArray);
        finally
          if assigned(FDQuery) then FDQuery.Free;
        end;

      //for loop filling the 2d array...

      date := System.DateUtils.IncDay(date, 1);
      Inc(d);
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        Result := false;
        break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

ConvertData's implementation is this :

```
procedure ConvertData(args);
var
//var decl
begin

  if not assigned(queryObj) then
    raise Exception.Create('Query object is unassigned.');

  with queryObj do
  begin
    // Prepare the SQL statement (obfuscated for demonstration)
    SQL.Text := 'SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 FROM ' + tableName + ' WHERE dateColumn=:param1 AND siteColumn=:param2';
    ParamByName('param1').AsDate := dateParam;
    ParamByName('param2').AsInteger := siteID;

    try
      Open;
      if (Recordcount = 0) then exit;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        ShowMessage('Error executing query: ' + E.Message);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  try
    // Create and initialize memory streams
    commentsStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    dataStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    attrStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

    try
      // Copy blob data to memory streams (obfuscated for demonstration)
      commentsBlob := queryObj.CreateBlobStream(queryObj.FieldByName('col4'), bmRead);
      if assigned(commentsBlob) then
        commentsStream.CopyFrom(commentsBlob, queryObj.FieldByName('col1').AsInteger);

      dataBlob := queryObj.CreateBlobStream(queryObj.FieldByName('col5'), bmRead);
      if assigned(dataBlob) then
        dataStream.CopyFrom(dataBlob, queryObj.FieldByName('col2').AsInteger);

      attrBlob := queryObj.CreateBlobStream(queryObj.FieldByName('col6'), bmRead);
      if assigned(attrBlob) then
        attrStream.CopyFrom(attrBlob, queryObj.FieldByName('col3').AsInteger);

    // Convert streams to array

    with queryObj do
    begin
      Close;
    end;

    SetLength(attrArray, maxIndex);

    for counter1 := Low(attrArray) to High(attrArray) do
      attrArray[counter1] := NaN;

    ConvertStreamToData(attrStream, attrArray, tempNumericArray);

    SetLength(dataArray, maxIndex + maxIndex);
    SetLength(commentsArray, maxIndex + maxIndex);

    for counter1 := Low(dataArray) to High(dataArray) do
      dataArray[counter1] := NaN;

    for counter2 := Low(commentsArray) to High(commentsArray) do
      commentsArray[counter2] := '';

    ConvertCommentsStream(commentsStream, commentsArray, tempStringArray);
    ConvertDataStream(dataStream, dataArray, tempNumericArray);

    // Additional processing
    dateObj := SomeUtility.DecodeDateFunction(dateParam);

    for loopCounter := Low(attrArray) to High(attrArray) do
    begin
        dataArray[maxIndex + loopCounter] := attrArray[loopCounter];
    end;

    finally
      // Free the memory streams
      commentsStream.Free;
      dataStream.Free;
      attrStream.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error in ConvertData: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The access violations occur on lines where I Open, close, or Free FDQuery, and seemingly always on the second time the function is called. Despite the query being created, opened, closed and freed on each loop iteration, it still throws these exceptions as if the objects aren't valid.

A post with a similar problem to mine from 10 years ago can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539738/access-violation-in-query-in-delphi-xe2), although the solution doesn't work or make sense.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

some question and advices below:

1. Put FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil); before try;
2. Why do you create and assign fdconnection in the while?
3. What does Inc(d) it means? What's that 'd'?
4. Do you close your query somewhere?
5. Your query should be created before the while. Also take into account performances

Comment: 6. `if assigned(X) then X.Free;` is always exactly equivalent to `X.Free`. You never check for `Assigned(X)` before `X.Free`.

Comment: And, to make the very important point #1 even more clear: `Frog := TFrog.Create; try { Use Frog } finally Frog.Free; end` is always the pattern you use. Always "ctor before `try`". Never "`try` before ctor".

Comment: 7. Don't use `try..except` with message boxes. Let the exception reach the app's exception handler instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I wasn't creating and assigning the FDQuery before, but since I've had many access violations I tried creating and deleting the FDQuery each time I call the function, to have a good grasp on the object's lifecycle. The query is closed inside ConvertData (that also triggers access violations). Initially, I wrote these in a test project with an FDQuery1 I drag/dropped onto the form, and it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).